# I need gem were user can vote for my ruby on rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to make an site where user can post a pic and challenge someone. Then rest of users voting which one is better. Is there any gem for my Ruby on rails site to help me? or I just need cowrite ir form scratch?

Comment: You can use "act_as_votable" gem.

Comment: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Answer (score 0):

There are gems to handle voting on a site like

1. Thumbsup site : https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up
2. MakeVotable site: https://github.com/medihack/make_voteable
3. ActsAsVotable site: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

They are based on Active record.
Hope this provides adequate direction towards the solution you seek.